# На мобилке <iframe> не выводит содержимое pdf

Tags: html, iframe

Вывожу на страницу содержимое pdf файла через

```
<iframe width="100%" height="900px" frameborder="0" src="/files/price_bs.pdf#toolbar=0&amp;scrollbar=0&amp;navpanes=1"></iframe>
```

На пк всё отображается нормально. Но на мобилке iframe не получает содержимое, браузер пишет

no enabled plugin supports this MIME type

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема

Comment: Ну, очевидно, мобилка в целом или мобилкин браузер в частности не поддерживают pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-умолчанию браузеры не читают pdf-формат. Этим занимаются сторонние плагины, установленные в сам браузер, либо программы в ОС, способные перехватить в браузере запросы на PDF и отобразить их не посредственно в браузере. IFRAME предполагает именно отображение контента, соответственно не отдаст файл на скачивание.

И тут приходим к самой сути проблемы, на телефоне у вас нет ни плагина, ни программы, способной перехватить и отобразить PDF, соответственно браузер выдает ошибку, что не поддерживает такой тип данных для отображения.

Вам нужно либо интегрировать какой-то просмотрщик pdf в сам сайт, либо воспользоваться онлайн-сервисами хранения документов с функцией шаринга.

Comment: А можете посоветовать какой нибудь просмоторщик pdf файлов на сайт?

Comment: Давно с этим не сталкивался, попробуйте прикрутить pdfjs https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js